# Unable to copy/paste in MinGW shell

Tags: mingw, copy-paste

I just installed MinGW on Windows and I'm unable to copy/paste as I am used to on Linux or even PuTTY. What is the trick for copying and pasting text (e.g. from chrome) into MinGW shell?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Right-click on the title bar of the command window and select 'Properties', then on the 'Options' tab tick the box for the 'QuickEdit mode', then click 'Ok'.

After that you can paste text from the clipboard using the right mouse-button, highlight text while holding down the left mouse-button and copy selected text using the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

**This procedure works on Windows 7/8, not Windows 10.**

Comment: N.b. You have to uncheck the 'Insert Mode' option as well.

Comment: Weird, my MinGW git bash terminal does not have a Properties item. It does however have these two options: 1) Press the `insert` key on your keyboard to paste and 2) Right-click the terminal->Options->Mouse->"Right click action" RadioButton:`Paste` to rc-paste

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I assume you're running Windows 10? My answer handles Windows command prompts prior to Windows 10.

Comment: And if you want a keyboard shortcut for this and find yourself on a Mac keyboard with no `insert` key, it would be `ctrl`+`shift`+`fn`+`return` per https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/169164/58120

Answer (score 38):

[Alternative] For MINGW64 (mintty 2.7.9) terminal in Windows 10, you can enable "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> shortcuts" to perform copy with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and paste with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).

To enable the feature:

1. right-click command window
2. Click on 'Keys'
3. Check the box for '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> shortcuts'

When you vi/vim into a file:

- To copy: highlight the portion you want and click 'y'
- To cut: highlight the portion you want and click 'd'
- To paste: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

Comment: @parsecer Sorry that my answer didn't help you, but does this justify a downvote? It seems as if my answer is not so wrong for quite some people. And as I already added to my answer my solution doesn't apply to Windows 10.

Comment: The section about vim is helpful, however in order to paste something pressing 'p' worked, 'ctrl'+'shift'+'v' did not.

Answer (score 8):

This mintty bug [CTRL + C & CTRL + V copy paste](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/602) addresses the issue. It allows normal Control-C, Control-V copy and pasting, but at the expense of changing other control characters. So to stop a process running you need Control-Shift-C, to interrupt it you would need Control-Shift-Z and to send an EOT you need Control-Shift-D. You may find the advantage of windows copy and paste outwights the disadvantages.

The behavior needs a flag to be set in the `.minttyrc` file. WHich should look like

```
CtrlShiftShortcuts=yes
CtrlExchangeShift=yes
```

Comment: Correct answer for 2019+

Comment: Worked for me in 2021

Comment: Worked for me in 2022.

Answer (score 7):

Win7 running MINGW64 (*mintty 2.7.3*) which came with the current version of [Git Bash *2.1.3.0*](https://git-scm.com/download/win) from date of this comment.

Right click title bar of shell > `Mouse` >  under `Click actions` > `Right mouse button` > select the `Paste` radio button.

However, I was surprised to find this didn't allow me to paste using my right click on my mouse.

I had to also select `Application mouse mode` > `Default click target` > `Window`

After changing both settings I was able to paste.

So it seems the new shell that comes with the current version of Git bash has new features.  It also seems to be a bit buggy.  For instance running an an executable via cli (e.g. `php -version` results in empty output and forces me to restart the shell).  Waiting for a new update, hopefully which will fix this.

Answer (score 5):

@mrt's solution above is permanent. Here's a quicker way for any 16bit prompt in Windows:

**COPY**

Click on the icon on the top left > Edit > Mark, select the text and then right-click

**PASTE**

Similar process as above (use Edit > Paste) OR just press `INSERT` key

Comment: Yes, my solution is permanent and that's why I think it's quicker than clicking on the top left icon every time I need to copy/paste something. :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and above solutions didn't work for Windows 10. This is because there is no Properties on the Menu. However with the above solution content, I was able to resolve it for Windows 10 as follows:
Right click the icon on the top left hand corner of MINGW64:
Select Options
Now Select keys
On the right hand you will find Shortcuts
If not thicked, thick Copy and Paste
Now always remeber the instruction given to copy & paste as follows:
  Copy:  Ctrl+ Ins (insert)
i.e. To copy on MINGW, only highlight whatever you want to copy, then press Ctrl Insert keys
  Paste; Shift+ Ins (insert)
i.e. To paste, place your cursor where you want paste. Then press Shift Insert keys

Now select Mouse
On the right hand you will find Mouse functions
If not thicked,  thick Copy on select and Copy as rich text
For mouse button, thick Right mouse paste
Note: to copy on MINGW, simply highlight whatever you want to copy. Then place your cursor where you want paste. then click the mouse right button.
Now click save or Apply then Save.
I have tried these and everything is fine.
Note that you can also copy from any other source and use paste to MINGW using the paste instructions above.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer running the MSYS2 shell inside [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) or [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console). This allows setting right-lick for paste and copy on select, just like in Linux and PuTTY. It also combines multiple MSYS2 shells in one window with tabs.

Windows 11 also has a similar terminal program now, but I haven't tried it yet with MSYS2...