# Docker on Windows (Boot2Docker) - certificate signed by unknown authority error

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I am running Docker on Windows (boot2docker + Oracle Virtual Box). In my corporate environment they modify the certificates so that the CAs are the company's self signed CA's. Thus, the chain ends up like this:

```
Company's CA
    |__
        Company's Intermediate CA
            |__
               Docker Certificate
```

When I try to run any command, such as:

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get this error:

```
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have found several answers to this problem but always for Linux environments. How can I workaround this problem in Windows?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This general issue has been plaguing me for a couple of months. I first noticed it when trying to get a local virtual machine to fetch Python packages, so I already had an idea that certificates would be an issue. I solved it for my VMs, but hadn't until today been able to work out a solution for Docker. The trick is to add the certificates to Docker's cert store and have them persist. This is accomplished by using a `bootlocal.sh` script that executes every time the machine starts.

I assume if you've already found the answers for Linux, you already know the first steps. I will document them here for the sake of being thorough, because others may not have gotten this far. Start with #3 below if you've already done #1 and #2 by way of previous attempts.

1. Get the set of corporate root certificates, which should be installed in your corporate-configured browser. In Chrome, you can go to Settings, click Show advanced settings, and scroll down to HTTPS/SSL, where you can choose Manage Certificates. My organization has put them in Trusted Root Certification Authorities and named them after the organization. Export each (I have two), one at a time. You can either choose **DER format** and do step #2 below to convert to **PEM**, or you can choose **Base-64 encoded x.509 (.CER)** and simply rename the extension to **.pem** and skip step #2.
2. Once you have them saved to a known location, you will want to convert them to PEM format unless you save as such. The easiest way I found to do this was to run the openssl.exe[1] command from within the Docker Quickstart Terminal.

   ```
   openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
   ```
3. Once you have the .pem files, you will want to copy them to a location to which your Docker machine has access to. Typically for MS Windows, you'll have /c/Users of the host machine automatically mounted inside your docker machine. I made a directory in `c:\Users\<my.username>\certs` and copied them there.
4. This step may not be strictly necessary, but it's what I did, and it works. You will want to copy those certificates into your boot2docker partition, which is persistent. I am connecting to my default machine, which IS something you will need to do for Step 5.

   ```
   MINGW64:$ docker-machine ssh default

   docker@default:~$ sudo -s
   root@default:/home/docker# mkdir /var/lib/boot2docker/certs
   root@default:/home/docker# cp /c/Users/my.username/certs/*.pem /var/lib/boot2docker/certs/
   ```
5. Now it's time to write a bootlocal.sh script, which will copy the certificates to the proper location each time the system starts.[2] If you haven't already, open an SSH connection to the machine, per Step 4.

   ```
   touch /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh && chmod +x /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
   vi /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
   ```

Insert the following and save the file:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d && cp /var/lib/boot2docker/certs/*.pem /etc/docker/certs.d
```

6. Restart the machine, either by using the reboot command from within the machine, or by using the docker-machine command from the Docker terminal:

   ```
   docker-machine restart default
   ```

Now you should be able to run 'hello-world' and others.

---

Sources

[1] https://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-to-convert-a-cer-file-in-pem

[2] https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/347#issuecomment-189112043

Comment: In addition to the above steps, I had to download the certificate from `"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"`, convert to `*.pem` and copied to `/etc/docker/certs.d` , only then it worked! But these steps helped me a lot figuring this out.

Comment: If you want an easier time pasting these commands, enable "QuickEdit Mode" in MINGW64 (right-click title bar > Options > QuickEdit Mode). https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363972/1455558

Comment: +1 What I would like to add is that you can look at the log files in /var/log as `bootlocal.log`, `boot2docker.log` and `docker.log` provide good details of what's happening behind the scenes to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: This worked for me like a charm, I wasn't able to do the "docker pull selenium/hub" after all this, I am now able to do all this good stuff. I had ZScaler certificates.

Answer (score 6):

A way to do it
With Firefox, go to url: https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fhello-world%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io, click view details for the certificate and extract it as crt.

Copy the file to VM where the os stores the crt:

CentOS

```
etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
# Then run
update-ca-trust force-enable
update-ca-trust extract
```

Ubuntu

```
/usr/share/ca-certificates
#Then run
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

Reboot docker, and it should work

Comment: Ubuntu solution works like charm. Was stuck for the whole day with this issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For exporting certificate, you can choose file format as "**Base-64 encoded x.509(.CER)**" and finally rename the certificate extension as **.pem**.