# Unable to use docker due to ZScaler and certificate issues

Tags: linux, docker, certificate, photon-os, zscaler

I have VMware Photon OS running in VMware Player. This will be used as the host OS to run Docker containers.

However, since I'm behind a ZScaler, I'm having issues running commands that access external resources. E.g. `docker pull python` gives me the following output (I added some line breaks to make it more readable):

```
error pulling image configuration: 
Get https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/a0/a0d32d529a0a6728f808050fd2baf9c12e24c852e5b0967ad245c006c3eea2ed/data
?Expires=1493287220
&Signature=gQ60zfNavWYavBzKK12qbqwfOH2ReXMVbWlS39oKNg0xQi-DZM68zPi22xfDl-8W56tQmz5WL5j8L39tjWkLJRNmKHwvwjsxaSNOkPMYQmhppIRD0OuVwfwHr-
1jvnk6mDZM7fCrChLCrF8Ds-2j-dq1XqhiNe5Sn8DYjFTpVWM_
&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have tries to extract the CA root certificates (in `PEM` format) for ZScaler from my Windows workstation, and have appended them to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. But even after restarting Docker, this didn't solve the issue.

I've read through numerous posts, most referencing the command `update-ca-trust` which does not exist on my system (even though the `ca-certificates` package is installed).

I have no idea how to go forward. AFAIK, there are two options. Either:

- Add the ZScaler certificates so SSL connections are trusted.
- Allow insecure connections to the Docker hub (but even then it will probably still complain because the certificate isn't trusted).

The latter works by the way, e.g. executing `curl` with the `-k` option allows me to access any https resource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is zscaler is acting as MAN-IN-THE-MIDDLE doing the ssl inspecting in your organization (see https://support.zscaler.com/hc/en-us/articles/205059995-How-does-Zscaler-protect-SSL-traffic-).

Since you've tried put the certificate in docker, I guess you've been already familiar with steps described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454369/1443505. The answer in this is almost correct for the zscaler scenario. One thing need to note is that because zscaler intercepts the CA tree. We need add all the certificates on the chains.

For now, the certificate chains behind zscaler looks as following

[image]

We need to export them all one by one and follow the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454369/1443505 for each of them.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was enough to follow the mentioned instructions for the "Zscaler Root CA" certificate. Anyway thanks for pointing out the solution!