# Configure Docker with proxy per host/url

Tags: docker, http-proxy, docker-toolbox, https-proxy-agent

I use Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 in a corporate environment. My workflow requires pulling containers from one artifactory and pushing them to a different one (eg. external and internal). Each artifactory requires a different proxy to access it. Is there a way to configure Docker daemon to select proxy based on a URL? Or, if not, what else can I do to make this work?

Comment: I don't think that's possible using Docker only. What's wrong in setting a proxy before puling from external artifactory, then setting another proxy for pushing to the other? With a wrapper script this may be a proper solution.

Comment: Thought about it, the only way I know of to do that using Docker Toolbox would be to ssh into the docker-machine, edit boot2docker shell script and then run `docker-machine restart`. Not very convenient every you want to push/pull an artifactoty, not to mention it kills all running containers. Is the another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as Pierre B. [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189728/configure-docker-with-proxy-per-host-url#comment97129194_55189728), [Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) does not support URL-based proxy selection, the solution is to point it to a local proxy configured to select the proper upstream proxy based on the URL.

While any HTTP[S] proxy capable of upstream selection would do, ([pac4cli](https://github.com/tkluck/pac4cli#proxy-auto-discovery-for-command-line-applications-pac4cli) project being particularly interesting for it's advertised capability to select the upstream based on [proxy-auto-discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol) protocol used by most Web browsers a in corporate setting), I've chosen to use [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/), as more mature and light-weight solution. Furthermore, I've decided to run my proxy inside the `docker-machine` VM in order to simplify it's deployment and make sure the proxy is always running when the Docker daemon needs it.

Below are the steps I used to set up my system. I'm especially grateful to [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906518/phoenix) for providing [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038417/1566634) to set up Docker Toolbox on Windows behind a corporate proxy, and will borrow heavily from that answer.

From this point on I will assume either [Docker Quickstart Terminal](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) or [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/download/win), with docker in the `PATH`, as your command line console and that "username" is your Windows user name.

## Step 1: Build `tinyproxy` on your target platform

Begin by pulling a clean Linux distribution, I used [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/), and run `bash` inside it:

```
docker run -it --name=centos centos bash
```

Next, install the tools we'll need:

```
yum install -y make gcc
```

After that we pull the [latest release](https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/releases) of Tinyproxy from it's GitHub repository and extract it inside root's home directory (at the time of this writing the latest release was 1.10.0):

```
cd
curl -L https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/releases/download/1.10.0/tinyproxy-1.10.0.tar.gz \
    | tar -xz
cd tinyproxy-1.10.0
```

Now let's configure and build it:

```
./configure --enable-upstream \
    --disable-filter\
    --disable-reverse\
    --disable-transparent\
    --disable-xtinyproxy
make
```

While `--enable-upstream` is obviously required, disabling other default features is optional but a good practice. To make sure it actually works run:

```
./src/tinyproxy -h
```

You should see something like:

```
Usage: tinyproxy [options]

Options are:
  -d        Do not daemonize (run in foreground).
  -c FILE   Use an alternate configuration file.
  -h        Display this usage information.
  -v        Display version information.

Features compiled in:
    Upstream proxy support

For support and bug reporting instructions, please visit
<https://tinyproxy.github.io/>.
```

We exit the container by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and copy the executable to a special folder location accessible from the `docker-machine` VM:

```
docker cp centos://root/tinyproxy-1.10.0/src/tinyproxy \
    /c/Users/username/tinyproxy
```

Substitute "username" with your Windows user name. Please note that double slash — `//` before "root" is required to disable MINGW path conversion.

Now we can delete the container:

```
docker rm centos
```

## Step 2: Point docker daemon to a local proxy port

Choose a TCP port number to run the proxy on. This can be any port that is not in use on the `docker-machine` VM. I will use number 8618 in this example.

First, let's delete the existing default Docker VM:
**WARNING:** This will permanently erase all currently stored containers and images

```
docker-machine rm -f default
```

Next, we re-create the default machine setting `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to the local host and the port we selected, and then refresh our shell environment:

```
docker-machine create default \
    --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8618 \
    --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:8618
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

Optionally, we could also set `NO_PROXY` environment variable to list hosts and/or wildcards (separated by `;`) to which the daemon should connect directly, bypassing the proxy.

## Step 3: Set up `tinyproxy` inside `docker-machine` VM

First, we will create two files in the `/c/Users/username` directory (this is where our `tinyproxy` binary should reside after **Step 1** above) and then we'll copy them to the VM.

The first file is `tinyproxy.conf`, the exact syntax is documented on the Tinyproxy website, but the example below should have all the settings need:

```sh
# These settings can be customized to your liking,
# the port though must be the same we used in Step 2

listen 127.0.0.1
port 8618

user nobody
group nogroup
loglevel critical
syslog on

maxclients 50
startservers 2
minspareServers 2
maxspareServers 5

disableviaheader yes

# Here is the actual proxy selection, rules apply from top
# to bottom, and the last one is the default. More info on:
# https://tinyproxy.github.io/

upstream http proxy1.corp.example.com:80 ".foo.example.com"
upstream http proxy2.corp.example.com:80 ".bar.example.com"
upstream http proxy.corp.example.com:82
```

In the example above:

- `http://proxy1.corp.example.com:80` will be used to connect to URLs that end with "foo.example.com", such as `http://www.foo.example.com`
- `http://proxy2.corp.example.com:80` will be used to connect to URLs that end with "bar.example.com", such as `http://www.bar.example.com`, and
- `http://proxy.corp.example.com:80` will be used to connect all other URLs

It is also possible to match exact host names, IP addresses, subnets and hosts without domains.

The second file is as the shell script that will launch the proxy, its name must be `bootlocal.sh`:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

# Terminate on error
set -e

# Switch to the script directory
cd $(dirname $0)

# Launch proxy server
./tinyproxy -c tinyproxy.conf
```

Now, let's connect to the docker VM, get root, and switch to boot2docker directory:

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo -s
cd /var/lib/boot2docker
```

Next, we'll copy all three files over and a set their permissions:

```
cp /c/Users/username/boot2docker/{tinyproxy{,.conf},bootlocal.sh} .
chmod 755 tinyproxy bootlocal.sh
chmod 644 tinyproxy.conf
```

Exit VM session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice and restart it:

```
docker-machine restart default
```

That's it! Now `docker` should be able pull and push images from different URLs automatically selecting the right proxy server.